# SQLite: Delete all of rest duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sqlite

query that return all unique (not duplicate) records:

```
select distinct notificationDate, ownerKey 
FROM notification_invoice 
where notificationDate >= 1536019200000 
and providerId in ("1234","567")
```

Now I need query that delete all rest (duplicate) inverse records in this table.
How I can do this in sqlite?

Comment: What is an "inverse" record?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: inverse - rest duplicate records

Comment: Do this table have a primary key (i.e. a value/column unique to each record) ?

Comment: @krokodilko column "_id" is a primary key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite: Get error when try to delete with alias name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597428/sqlite-get-error-when-try-to-delete-with-alias-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that `_id` is a primary key, then the below query will delete all redundant duplictes:

```
DELETE FROM notification_invoice t1
WHERE notificationDate >= 1536019200000 
  and providerId in ("1234","567") 
  AND EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM notification_invoice t2
     WHERE t2.notificationDate = t1.notificationDate 
       and t1.ownerKey = t2.ownerKey 
       and providerId in ("1234","567") 
       AND t1._id < t2._id
  )
```

Comment: error: Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "t1": syntax error)
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 1

Comment: @George Joseph I don't understand too - it was not me who clicked downvote on your answer..

Comment: i upvoted your answer to not make it a -1 and have it as an accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information provided that _id is a primary key.

You can delete all records where _id is not the max(_id) value per notificationdate,ownerkey

```
delete
  from notification_invoice a
where a._id not in (select max(b._id)
                      FROM notification_invoice b
                     where b.notificationDate >= 1536019200000 
                       and b.providerId in ("1234","567") 
                    group by b.notificationdate
                         ,b.ownerKey
                   )
```

Comment: Error: Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "a": syntax error)
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 1