# SQLite: Get error when try to delete with alias name

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite my query:

```
DELETE FROM notification_invoice t1 WHERE notificationDate >= 1536883200000  and providerId in ("1234","5678") 
    AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM notification_invoice t2  WHERE 
         providerId in ("1234","5678") 
         and t2.notificationDate = t1.notificationDate          
         and t1.ownerKey = t2.ownerKey 
         AND t1._id < t2._id
    )
```

But I get error:

```
Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "t1": syntax error)
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 1
```

Comment: If you remove the EXISTS condition, will you still get the error?

Comment: @jarlh yes, get same error

Comment: Now remove the complete WHERE clause. Keep `DELETE FROM notification_invoice t1`. Any error? Note, you will delete all data if it works, never try this on a production database!

Comment: DELETE FROM notification_invoice t1 (
         SELECT 1 FROM notification_invoice t2  WHERE .... - get same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832338/575376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite delete with table alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832199/sqlite-delete-with-table-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite **does** support table aliases with `DELETE`, you're just using the wrong syntax. You need to use `AS` between the table name and alias:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(bar);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('dog');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
bar       
----------
dog       
sqlite> DELETE FROM foo AS f WHERE f.bar = 'dog';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
sqlite>
```

If you look at the syntax diagrams in the [documentation for DELETE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), in particular the *qualified-table-name* one, you'll see that the `AS` isn't optional like it is in a `SELECT` table name.

Comment: Not help: DELETE FROM notification_invoice AS t1 WHERE notificationDate ... - Error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "DELETE": syntax error)
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 1

Comment: @Alexei what version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: sqlite-jdbc-3.8.10.1.jar

Comment: @Alexei that's pretty old.

Comment: Is this a last version: 3.25.2  ?

Comment: @Alexei that's a pretty recent one. You can always see what the current version is at https://sqlite.org

Answer (score 1):

Removing the use of the alias, on the table being deleted from, will fix the syntax error.

```
DELETE FROM notification_invoice
WHERE notificationDate >= 1536883200000
  AND providerId in ("1234","5678") 
  AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM notification_invoice t2
          WHERE t2.providerId in ("1234","5678") 
            AND t2.notificationDate = notification_invoice.notificationDate          
            AND t2.ownerKey         = notification_invoice.ownerKey 
            AND t2._id              > notification_invoice._id
    )
```

Whether the logic is correct is impossible to say as you haven't described the data or the logic you index to implement.

Maybe the sub-query should have `t2.providerId = notification_invoice.provider_id`.  We can't tell, without knowing the data, the constraints, the intended logic, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE` statement operates on a single table and can not use a table alias.  The alias is causing your error.

See [stackoverflow.com/a/15832338/2577062](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832338/2577062) for a similar situation.

Comment: If I'm not use alias "t1" - no error. But query return incorrect result.

Comment: @Alexei - If you SHOUT at us, do you really think we'll try to help you!?!?!??!?!

Comment: Great, sounds like your question is answered.  The incorrect result is very likely due to some logic error in your WHERE clause and EXISTS condition.  You'll have to figure this out on your own.